# Bitnami Parse server - set public folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, parse-server, bitnami

I trying to migrate my parse hosting to my migrated parse app on AWS.

my app server & dashboard are working, i only need to set my public folder.

right now I'm getting **Service Unavailable** error when enter my domain:

[chabadworld.net](http://chabadworld.net)

my parse app is on chabadworld.net:1337/parse

what should i configure to load my parse/public/index.html as homepage

Comment: Hi, this domain works properly for me. Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: i launch new clean linux instance and run node.js server listen to port 80